# Trying to use the Search API in .NET but I doesnt seem to work

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, .net, search-api

What I am trying to do is to Get all sites from the search API.

This REST API url works perfect: `http://localhost/_api/search/query?querytext='path:http://localhost/teamsites/*+OR+path:http://localhost/supportsite/*+OR+path:http://localhost/funsite/*'&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=50&refinementfilters='contentclass:equals("STS_Web")'`

I get 17 sites with that rest url.

This is in .NET CSOM:

```
    using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
    {
        var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(SPContext.Current.Site);
        keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = true;
        keywordQuery.QueryText =
            "path:http://localhost/teamsites/* OR path:http://localhost/funsite/* OR path:http://localhost/supportsite/*";
        keywordQuery.RowLimit = 200;
        keywordQuery.RefinementFilters.Add("contentclass:equals('STS_Web')");
        var searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
        ResultTableCollection results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var s in results)
        {
            var l = s.ResultRows;


        }

    }
```

Note: It seems that the problem is in refinmentFilters method.

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: you mean  keywordQuery.RefinementFilters.Add("contentclass:STS_Web); etc?

Comment: I will try that

Comment: Didnt work :/ tried both = and : in the QueryText

Comment: Too bad, have you looked at the example for using refinments here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394639(v=office.15).aspx